# Azure tables: how to use partition key and row key when entities have only one key?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

My understanding is that in an Azure table, each entity has a composite key made up of the **partition key** and **row key**, and the **partition key** should be used as a category which entities are grouped by, with the **row key** being a unique id for a particular entity within a category.

However, I want to store a table of extremely simple entities which have just one simple key, and I'm not sure of what roles the **partition key** and **row key** should play for such an entity.

*for example*

```
part : { id: '00001',
         name: 'wotsit',
         weight: '50kg' }
```

Semantically, it feels most correct to store `id` as the **row key** and use the same, probably blank, **partition key** for all entities (i.e. they're all in the same, default category). However I'm far more interested in getting maximum lookup performance than table semantics. I can easily abstract this away in the code.

So my question is, **how should I use partition key / row key when entities have only one simple key to get maximum lookup performance**?

My guess is that storing `id` as the **partition key**, and using a blank **row key** for every entity, would be best as the **partition key** is looked up first in queries?

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at Azure tables it to recognize that really there is only one composite key, split into partition and row sub-keys, to support a user determined scalability strategy.

So, you could arbitrary split you single key in to the 2 sub keys based on how they would scale best, determined by the nature of the data.

In your example you could split the id into Partition Key = "00" and Row Key = "001". This may not appear to be useful in your key range but for longer keys may make more sense.

Comment: thanks for the input - the example is a bit rubbish but let's assume the key really is atomic - randomly generated 5 digit number for example - and can't be meaningfully broken down. Is there any intrinsic advantage to using both the partition and row key by just inventing an arbitrary split? Perhaps I don't understand the scalability piece enough

Comment: My response was more generic rather than specific to your question. For a small data range it should not matter either way.
For a large data set, you do not want all the rows to be in a single partition since a partition is restricted to a single physical 'node' and could max out in storage space.

Comment: Sure, so the partitions literally mean the table data may be split across nodes? I think I will go with using the partition key then, seems like there's less downside. To be honest, as you say, it's likely that there won't be enough data in this table for it to matter either way but I was interested in if there was some obvious performance advantage of one over the other.