# Azure table storage partition key and row key for one key entity

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

What is the best practice when choosing partition & row key for entities with one important key?

Sample entities:

- Device1:

  - ID: AB1234567
  - IsRunning: Yes
  - IsUpdating: No
- Device2:

  - ID: AB7654321
  - IsRunning: Yes
  - IsUpdating: Yes

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008577/azure-tables-how-to-use-partition-key-and-row-key-when-entities-have-only-one-k) that suggests splitting the ID as partition key and row key.

But [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/designing-a-scalable-partitioning-strategy-for-azure-table-storage#r) actually recommends only using partition key when the entity only has one key property. It doesn't say what should be set as the row key though.. should it be empty? Or maybe a default value like '0'?

The expected records is maybe in the tens of thousands. Currently ~10k but growing